# How to find same subfolders in two folders on first level only?

Tags: command-line, directory, diff, duplicate

Scenario:

- 2 main folders, that may have subfolders with the same names (I do not know what names might be duplicated, that's what I am trying to find)
- the subfolders have MANY other files & subfolders so tools with automatic recursion are not really an option
- I only care about duplicate subfolder names on the first level of the two main folders
- contents of the subfolders don't matter
- contents of the files don't matter

I tried using `meld` GUI but that just takes endless time to finish for these structures.

I tried using `diff --brief --report-identical-files folder1 folder2` but that basically reports everything and it does not even include the folders so I can't even `| grep identical`.

Am I using wrong tools? Or is there some trick that I didn't get from `diff --help` ? Or am I doing something wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd use a simple `find`:

```
find "/path/to/main1" "/path/to/main2" -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d -printf '%f\n' | sort | uniq -d
```

Or to make it zero-terminated to prevent issues with newline characters:

```
find "/path/to/main1" "/path/to/main2" -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1  -type d -printf '%f\0' | sort -z | uniq -zd | xargs -0
```

Comment: @jave.web don't copy: make a new folder, then make symlinks to your two target directories in this new folder and use `find -L /path/to/new/folder -mindepth ....` (the `-L` tells `find` to follow symlinks). This way you don't need to duplicate the data.

Comment: Ok, after the edit, it works exactly as expected. (Note if you want same for files use `-type f` instead of `-type d`. @terdon thanks for the suggestion that's certainly an approach too

Answer (score 1):

Using `zsh`, given

```
% tree dir1 dir2
dir1
├── bar
└── foo
    └── baz
dir2
├── bar
│   └── baz
└── baz

6 directories, 0 files
```

then

```
% a=( dir1/*(/ND:t) ) ; b=( dir2/*(/ND:t) )
```

creates arrays of the **t**ails (basenames) of directories `/` in the two top-level directories `dir1` and `dir2` (with **D**otglob and **N**ullglob options enabled).

Then we can use an expansion of the form `${name:*arrayname}` to retain only elements that are present in both arrays:

```
% print -rC1 ${a:*b}
bar
```